# Utterly confused about OAuth and Google Calendar Gadget

Tags: oauth, google-calendar-api, google-gadget

I'm working on a Google Calendar Gadget and need to load data for the user from a remote server. It's simple stuff, like favorite color, but I need the user's ID. Using makeRequest works in general, but I need to send the account name, or a hash of it, or any sort of identifier to my server so it gets the right data. What's the easiest way to get that info? Currently it asks the user via HTML form, every single time it loads, which is pretty lame.

I've been looking at OAuth stuff, trying examples, and nothing works... I got an OAuth client key but don't know how/where to use it (or if I do use it with a Gadget). I found the Calendar feed/scope URI but I'm not really sure if that's correct to just get a user identifier, maybe I should use accounts. Half the examples are for OAuth 1.0...it's really frustrating.

Does anyone know a way to do this, or a good example/tutorial that explains how, for a Gadget? I think Gadgets are different since they run on Google's servers...but don't really know how this makes them different in this context.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to this: [osapi.people.get() returns 404 in google calendar sidebar gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810787/osapi-people-get-returns-404-in-google-calendar-sidebar-gadget/33919767#33919767). Then associate the google user ID with your internal ID, if different.