# osapi.people.get() returns 404 in google calendar sidebar gadget

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-gadget, opensocial

For an html-type calendar sidebar gadget with module prefs,

```
<Require feature="opensocial-0.9"/>
<Require feature="osapi" />
```

where calls to osapi.http all successfully send, this results in a 404 response:

```
osapi.people.get({userId:'@viewer'}).execute(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

This is wrapped in a POST to the same RPC endpoint as the osapi.http calls, with the post object as expected:

```
[{"method":"people.get","id":"people.get","params":{"userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"}}]
```

There was no difference in behavior with either osapi.http or osapi.people when the gadget Required either opensocial-0.8 or opensocial-0.9. I assumed that no auth token is required for this call--is that true? Does google calendar support osapi.people?

Answer (score 0):

I instead used the JS API Client Library and followed the sequence in [Authentication using the Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication). Your scopes can contain either explicit URLs or claims, such as 'openid' (see [OpenID Connect explained](http://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect)). This will result in a

```
GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=...
```

where the URL of the request parameter 'origin' (ex: https://....opensocial.googleusercontent.com) must be among your Authorized Javascript origins for your client in Google Developers Console.

The returned authResult should contain an access_token. If not, then possible causes of authResult.error_subtype...

- 'origin_mismatch': origin is not among authorized origins
- 'access_denied': scope didn't include identity URL or 'openid'